# How to connect to heating networks both with sources and consumers into one network?

Tags: heating-systems

We need to connect two distinct heating networks on a wastewater treatment plant into one. So far I've only seen heating networks with one central heat source or one central manifold that all heat sources feed into, but this time we have distributed sources.

Here's the state the system is now in:
network 1:
Natural gas boiler, several smallish consumers (two adjactant buildings)
network 2:
oil boiler, sewage gas CHP, several smallish and one big consumer (sveral buildings, spread aout about 100m apart)

Target state:
both networks (about 100m apart) are connected,
Manifold 1: 
one additional gas CHP, one additional largish consumer
Manifold 2:
no change

Manifold 1 should supply power to manifold 2 when needed, never the other way round.

My idea is to have connect both hot and cold sides and have pumps (hot side manifold 1 -> hot side manifold 2, cold side manifold 2 -> cold side manifold 1). The "hot" pump will be controlled for delta T between both manifolds, the cold pump should ensure hydraulic balance but I dont know a good control scheme for this.

Comment: A heat exchanger? So allows heat but allows different pressures for example...

Comment: Duplicate: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/29712/10902

Comment: accidental double post, deleted the other one.

Comment: A heat exchanger is the second option, because it would 'cost' me 5-10 K. But it would help with the hydraulic headaches ...

Comment: I sized a heat exchanger for two sources (one a solar heated water tank, the other a 30kW boiler) and those were at each end of the distribution system with 6 or so loads demanding in between... Was designed so both could input as necessary with solar having priority: cheaper... That exchanger was about 2k iirc

Comment: the heat exchanger was at the solar end? (seperating waer/glycol from water?) or how was the topology, where was the hydraulic compensator etc?

Comment: Solar was drainback - avoids the need for antifreeze on 5000 litres of water... actually a heat exchanger at both ends (solar end was a small 400L tank, boiler end was a flat plate exchanger sized to cope with future demand guessed at 70kW). Distribution system used a header tank sized to cope with expansion of water between low and high operating temperatures.

Comment: ok, this is no design I can copy easily due to what's built already.

Comment: Possibly ignorant question -- a good way to balance the pressure between two vessels is with a **pipe**, not a **pump** -- wouldn't that work on your cold side?  If the hot-side pump is not going, then the cold side doesn't exchange fluid?  Or, if there's a possibility of back-flow, a check valve?

Comment: The pressure drop over the ~100m pipe per way is likely too large (+ there should be a hydraulic compensator on both manifolds).